# without click append 3 rows, then click 1 row per click

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to open 3 row defult after addrow and remove row and apply remove defult 3 row using javascript
please share valuable idea sir

**I have need example:-**

[image]

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
       $("body").on('click', '.btn-add-more', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var $sr = ($(".jdr1").length + 1);
   var rowid = Math.random();
   
   var $html = '<tr class="jdr1" id="' + rowid + '">' +
           '<td><span class="btn btn-sm btn-default">' + $sr + '</span><input type="hidden" name="count[]" value="'+Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1)+'"></td>' +
           '<td><input type="text" required="" class="form-control input-sm title" placeholder="Medicine" name="medicine[]"></td>' +
           '<td><input type="text" name="medicine_qty[]" placeholder="Potency" class="form-control input-sm"></td>' +
           '<td><input type="text" name="medicine_time[]" placeholder="Description" class="form-control input-sm"></td>' +
           '<td><input type="text" name="remark[]" placeholder="Add/Note" class="form-control input-sm"></td>' + '<td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning btn-remove-detail-row"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">Remove</i></button>    </td>'+
           '</tr>';
   
   $("#table-details").append($html);
   
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the function in a for loop and edit the for loop limit according to your needs.

```js
$("body").on('click', '.btn-add-more', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var rows = $(".jdr1").length;
  var limit = 1;
  // In the first click append 3 rows, then 1 row per click
  if (rows < 3) limit = 3;
   for (let i=0; i<limit; i++) {
      var $sr = ($(".jdr1").length + 1);
      var rowid = Math.random();
      var $html = '<tr class="jdr1" id="' + rowid + '">' +
           '<td><span class="btn btn-sm btn-default">' + $sr + '</span><input type="hidden" name="count[]" value="'+Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1)+'"></td>' +
           '<td><input type="text" required="" class="form-control input-sm title" placeholder="Medicine" name="medicine[]"></td>' +
           '<td><input type="text" name="medicine_qty[]" placeholder="Potency" class="form-control input-sm"></td>' +
           '<td><input type="text" name="medicine_time[]" placeholder="Description" class="form-control input-sm"></td>' +
           '<td><input type="text" name="remark[]" placeholder="Add/Note" class="form-control input-sm"></td>' + '<td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning btn-remove-detail-row"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">Remove</i></button>    </td>'+
           '</tr>';
   
   $("#table-details").append($html);
   }
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<table id="table-details"></table>
<button class="btn-add-more">Add Rows</button>
</html>
```

Comment: my query defult open 3 row if need extra row than add one row again add

Comment: but your idea one click open 3 row but i have need defult 3 row open if need than add one by one sir

Comment: @Amitabhkumar sorry I couldn't understand what you are trying to do. Do you want to append 3 rows in the first click, and then only 1 row on next clicks?

Comment: without click show 3 row after click ane by one row sir

Comment: @Amitabhkumar I submitted my edited code. It checks for number of rows in the table. If they are less then 3, then it adds 3. After that limit is set to 1. So, if user clicks again only 1 row is added.

Comment: without click append 3 rows, then click 1 row per click i have need sir

Comment: Your initial code was already appending 1 row per click. You can just add the rows manually to the table initially. I don't get the point.

Comment: yes my initial code already appending 1 row without click but need total 4 row one initial code and 3 appending row than per click one row open sir

Comment: I'm sorry it's not possible to understand your changing requirements. I hope someone else can spend some time to understand and solve it.

Comment: I am wishing that 1 row is already open and 3 row is open without clicking if required,total 4 row show on page  if need extra row than per click add one row should be open?

Comment: hi any bosy can you help me?